# Fix a character to text input box using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, text, input, user-input

I am looking for a way to 'fix' a dollar symbol $ to a text input box eg `<input type="text" value="$" />` but make it not possible for the default value to be removed, so that whatever the user inputs, there is always a $ symbol 'prepending' input.

Cheers

Comment: Check my *[answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23908556/2260614)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is the possibility of a `background-image` but it's difficult to maintain, and doesn't react to font size changes, which makes it the less optimal choice IMO.

A better way in my opionion would be:

- Put a `<span>$</span>` next to the input (before it, actually).
- give it `position: relative; left: 20px`.
- The $ sign then moves into the input field.
- Then, give the input field `padding-left: 24px`.
- Voilá! The $ sign is in the input field, does not obscure anything, and cannot be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Pekka's answer, I used this on my page, but I automated it a little bit with jQuery. So for this example, all of the input fields that I want to put a $ symbol in, I give them a class of "cost".

### CSS:

```
<style type=&quot;text/css&quot; media="screen">
.cost{
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
input.cost{
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>
```

### jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#lcce form input.cost").wrap('<div class=&quot;cost">');
    $("#lcce form input.cost").before('<span class="cost"></span>');
});
</script/>
```

This will place the span with a class of "cost" right before your input, and also wrap a div around both the input, and the span, so they are ensured to be on the same line.

If you don't have jQuery, you can get it from: [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com)

Now I've got a quick question - I noticed that with this styling, in IE6,7, and 8, the $ symbol is not lined up correctly. Does anybody out there have a fix for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this as a visual effect only? If yes you could apply that with CSS as a background image on the input.

Afterwards, on the server, you can do whatever you want with the value (e.g prepend it with $).

Comment: This is a visual thing, to let people know that input will be in $ format e.g $22.00

Answer (score 0):

I too have been looking at different solutions for this.  Using css to indent the text with padding and putting a background image in that position is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
$('#price').keypress(function(event) {
var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if ($(this).val().indexOf('$') === -1){
    document.getElementById("price").value = "$" + $(this).val();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("price").value = $(this).val();
  }  
});
```

with `<input type="text" id="price">`.

User can remove the dollar sign manually though if he/she wants to.