# Adding a Dollar Sign to a Text Field Input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, I'm looking to automatically put a dollar sign in front of the entered amount in an input field within a form.  I'm using the below code, but am not sure what I'm missing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script>
var test = document.getElementById("name");
document.write("$"+test.value);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" id="name"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the dollar sign to be added there after the user finishes typing? What if there's already a dollar sign there?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the [MDN JavaScript Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Getting_Started) ...

Comment: I'd like to have the dollar sign there as soon as a user places their cursor into the input field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218434/fix-a-character-to-text-input-box-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if it works

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-a-input-field-with-javascript

Comment: Based on a good guess of what your current skill level in JS is, you'll save yourself a lot of work if you just put the $ outside the input box.

Comment: var test = document.getElementById("name");
test.value = "$"

Answer (score 4):

This is the way you would add the dollar sign: http://jsfiddle.net/VSuvA/.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" id="name" onblur="handleChange()"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function handleChange() {
   var myValue = document.getElementById("name").value;

   if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0)
   {
      myValue = "$" + myValue;
   }

   document.getElementById("name").value = myValue;
}
```

You have to listen to an event like `onchange` or `onblur` and then set the value back. `document.write` will not do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be something like:

```
Amount: $<input type="number" id="name" min="0" max="9999" step="0.01"/>
```

Comment: There's no `size` attribute when using `type=number` on an `input`.