# How to append input in the same field after entering text in it

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input field and I want to append its text while typing in it and persisting the previous value in it

Following is the code

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="type_name" value="Value1-" onchange="dosomething()">
```

What I want is when the user starts typing it the starting text of input field should remain there which is "Value1-" and append the text in it like "Value1-3433".

I hope you get my point a little help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more? is this fiddle ok for you? http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/1/

Comment: Well I want to append the input of the text on key presses while retaing the "Value1-" text and append the newly written text after it . More simple the input field will already be filled when the form is loaded with value "Value1-" and will be readonly all I want is the Value1- text to be readonly and I can edit and enter new text after it

Comment: Which means, user cant delete that "value1"?

Comment: yes user can't delete the value1.. you are correct

Comment: @ShakoorAlam Check my answer, it won't allow the user to delete `Value1-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want ?

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3XPHK/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('#txt1').on('keyup',function(){
    console.log($(this).val().substr( 0 , 7)) ;
    if($(this).val().substr( 0 , 7) != "Value1-") {
        $(this).val('Value1-');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="type_name" value="Value1-" >
```

Comment: Thank you for your support I have accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

If I got it correct,with pure JavaScript,this is what you need to do:

1. Call a function `start()` when the page loads with `<body onload="start()">`. Print the text "Value1-" in the input TextField. Since this function is called only once,the Value1- will be printed only once.
2. Create another `function append()` which you should call using `onchange()` and do:
   `document.getElementById('outputText').value=document.getElementById('txt1').value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: why to use `start()` only for setting value of text field?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd8vP/6/)***</kbd>

1. Append a label with `position:absolute`
   *HTML*

   `<label id="lbl" for="txt1"></label>
   <input type="text" id="txt1" name="type_name" value="" />`

   And fire an `onchange` event, to change add the `Value1-` and users input...
2. Add `Value1` `onchange` event

   `$('#txt2').change(function () {
         var str = $(this).val().replace('Value1-','');
         $(this).val('Value1-'+str);
     });`
3. **Finally**, I guess what you needed is here...

> `$('#txt3').keypress(function (e) {
>            var pos = $(this).getCursorPosition();
>            if (pos < 7 ||(pos==7 && e.keyCode == 8) ) {
>                e.preventDefault();
>            }
>      });`
>
> Source : Made with great support from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897510/2260614)** by @MarkB29

Comment: put your cursor between "Value1-" and type anything , it will allow you to type. That's bug. You should also check text field value, not only cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve this.

Jquery code:

```
$('#txt1').on('keyup',function(){

var str=$(this).val();
var newstr = str.substring(0, 7);

if(newstr != "Value1-")
{       
    $(this).val("Value1-");
}  

});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="type_name" value="Value1-">
```

Working Jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/spdZW/1/

Comment: delete only the '-' from 'Value1-', then add another character. See what happens then

Comment: It append another Value1-

Comment: still it's buggy, check again.