# Setting a default value to an input field in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set an input field a user can type into with a `£` sign fixed into that field. The user should not be able to delete or change this sign, but the user should be able to modify what comes after.

e.g.

1. initial `£`
2. user adds `10`, result: `£10`
3. user modified changes `10` -> `5000`, result: `£5000`
4. user deletes everything in the field, result: `£` remains

The placeholder tag does not work as this is not visible when entering something in the field.
The default value is also not doing quite what I want.

```
Place your stake: <input type="text" onChange={this.handleStakeChange}/>
```

Comment: Why dont you print that on label instead of textbox?

Comment: You can either 1. have a static label appear "on top" of the input. 2. format the value when the input changes, appending the currency sign.

Comment: having a static label seems resonable, not having to process input data much is good

Comment: @syedfaizan where would that live though?

Comment: @Imad I want it inside the input box if possible

Comment: @Theworm it will be a simple dom element which will be placed inside the input box using CSS, so it doesn't affect the value of the input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218434/fix-a-character-to-text-input-box-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS content generation before or after 'input' elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-or-after-input-elements)

Answer (score 3):

You can do so easily with CSS, and a background image:

```css
.pounds-input {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-finance-1-1/128/currency-sign-pound-128.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  background-position: 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<input class="pounds-input" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by simply placing an element with the symbol next to the `input` field and setting `padding-left` (or `text-indent`) on the `input` field itself:

```css
.currency {
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
}
input {
  padding-left: 12px;
  /* or text-indent: 12px; */
}
```

```html
<label>Place your stake:</label>
<span class="currency">£</span>
<input type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid styles and just do plain React. Input values should come from state and change should give a new state. It's the concept of "controlled components"

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

In this way you have full control on what goes and comes from input elements. The state is the source of truth.

```
var StakeInput = React.createClass( {
getInitialState: function(){
  return {stake: ''}
},
handleStakeChange: function(e){
  const stakeInputValue = e.target.value.replace(/£/g, '').trim()
  this.setState({
    stake: stakeInputValue
  });
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <div>
    Place your stake: 
      <input type="text" value={'£ ' + this.state.stake}
        onChange={this.handleStakeChange}/>
    </div>
  )

    }
});
React.render(<StakeInput />, document.getElementById('output'));
```

http://jsbin.com/jemasub/edit?html,js,output