# How to create static symbol in input field?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have simple input filed, that should works as a filed, where user provide just email domain:

```html
<input type="text" class="email-domain-input" v-model="providedDomain" placeholder="@test.com">
```

For now it looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to make symbol `@` static in this field, so user just won't be able to delete it. Just like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: This should help you get a solution [Fix a character to text input box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218454/15405352)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's what I was looking for! @groovy_guy